# PHP Function to grab the Featured Image (Wordpress) and Integrate in Pinterest Button

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code inserted in the Function. PHP file of my WordPress this. What it basically do is

If the user click on the Pinterest PIN IT Button, It checks the blog post page for the FIRST Image and return it to be *Pinned* in Pinterest.

Is it possible if someone can modify the code so that it will totally ignore all the images in the blog post page and instead **choose the Featured Image**?

**Catch the First image function:**

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "http://www.bendaggers.com/wp-content/themes/Lord%20of%20Avernus%20-%20Abaddon/Images/Deafult_Img.png";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

**Wordpress Featured Image:**

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Comment: What's the point if `ob_start()` and right after `and ob_end_clean()`? What do you expect this to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function catch_that_image( $size = 'full' ) {
    global $post;
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
        $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $size);
        return $featured_image[0];
    }
    return false;
}
```

It returns the featured image URL if one is set, `false` otherwise. You can also set the size in the function call, defaults to 'large'.

Comment: thank you @Peter Michael. Just a question with the $size = 'large', what if i dont want to assign a size so that it will capture the original size of the image? Should i just remove/delete the $size = 'large' attribute?

Comment: Updated answer. The function will now pull the original image unless you specify another size.