# PHP Conditional Function to grab different set of Images according to its availability for PINTEREST

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with this two Wordpress Function for my Pinterest Button. What i'm trying to achieve is the flow chart below.

[image]

**Function Catch That Image**

```
   function catch_that_image() {
      global $post, $posts;
      $first_img = '';
      ob_start();
      ob_end_clean();
      $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
      $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

      if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
        $first_img = "http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/Lord%20of%20Avernus%20-%20Abaddon/Images/Deafult_Img.png";
      }
      return $first_img;
    }
```

**Function Get Featured Image**

```
function get_featured_image( $size = 'full' ) {
    global $post;
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
        $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $size);
        return $featured_image[0];
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Wordpress Featured Thumbnail**

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

As you can see in my flow chart, I am trying to combine the two functions above. The problem is it's not working.

This is my code:

**Function Consolidated Pinterest Image Function**

```
function pinterest_image_snatcher($size = 'full' ) {
        global $post;
       if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
            $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $size);
            return $featured_image[0];
        }

else
      $first_img = '';
      ob_start();
      ob_end_clean();
      $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
      $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

      if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
        $first_img = "http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/Lord%20of%20Avernus%20-%20Abaddon/Images/Deafult_Img.png";
      }
      return $first_img;
    }
```

The first two functions above is working really fine but the third one is not! Could anyone help to consolidate the two function above. Everyone is welcome to modify the codes.

Please help me out Dear PHP Experts. My Code is messed up and **NOT** working. Do you mind to modify this according to the flow chart? thank you!

[How to add Pinterest button for WordPress Blogs](http://bit.ly/17Fe5I8)

Comment: Your else statement needs brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function pinterest_image_snatcher( $size = 'full' ) {

    global $post;
    $first_img = '';

    if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
        $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $size);
        $first_img = $featured_image[0];
    } else {
        $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
        $first_img = $matches[1][0];
        if( empty($first_img) ) {
            $first_img = "http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/Lord%20of%20Avernus%20-%20Abaddon/Images/Deafult_Img.png";
        }      
    }
    return $first_img;
}
```

I just fixed missing brackets as @royal-bg mentioned in the comments & changed logic a bit.

Comment: Hi @Peter Michael, remember the codes for "Function Get Featured Image"? You made that for me (see links below).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086148/php-function-to-grab-the-featured-image-wordpress-and-integrate-in-pinterest-b

Thank you very much for your help. I hope you got it right again.

Comment: Peter, your work is flawless! It's working! I need to reward you because its the second time you work your expertise for me.